# Trying to create a custom menu link in a menu

Tags: views, routes

So I want to have different menu links depending on if a user has received a message or not.

I make a hook_menu() instance, like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  global $user;
  $items = array();
  $items['user/' . $user->uid . '/messages'] = array(
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'title' => t('Messages'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

However it only takes me to my user page, and not the messages (which should be a view at the path specified).

Is there a way to make it so that I can directly go from this item link in the menu to the view?

Answer (score 0):

Got it from here:

http://zufelt.ca/blog/embedding-view-menu-hook-drupal

Changed my hook instance to this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  global $user;
  $items = array();
  $items['user/' . $user->uid . '/messages'] = array(
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'title' => t('Messages'),
    'page callback' => 'views_embed_view',
    'page arguments' => array('message_private', 'page_1'),
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'views'),
    'file' => 'views.module',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

This will embed the view into the hook_menu() instance.